# Find next string in a list of string

Tags: c#

I have a list of UserNames in a comma delimited string. I want to find next one of the input username. 
For Example:

```
var s0 = "abc,deF,ghi,jkl";
var s1 = "abc";
var s2 = "def";
var s3 = "ghi";
var s4 = "jkl";
```

Result should be:

```
NextInString(s0,s1 ) == "def"
NextInString(s0,s2 ) == "ghi"
NextInString(s0,s3 ) == "jkl"
NextInString(s0,s4 ) == "jkl"
```

Here is what I have:

```
string NextInString(string listOfNames, string userName)
{
    if(listOfNames == string.Empty || userName == string.Empty) 
        return string.Empty;

    var s = listOfNames.Split(',');
    var count = 0;
    foreach (var element in s)
    {
        if (element == userName)break;
        count++;
    }

    if (s.Length -1 == count)
    {
        return s[count];
    }
    else return s[ count + 1 ];
}
```

My question is, is there a better/easier way to approach this?

Comment: I'd like to help, but your code formatting caused my eyes to bleed and now I'm blind.

Comment: Someone helped me fixed. should fix your blindness now :) @itsme86

Comment: I'd like to point out that your current design requires reparsing your comma-delimited list every time the method is called. It would be *much* more performant to parse it once and pass in an `IEnumerable<string>` or `IList<string>`.

Comment: What if the item is not present in the list ? Do you return last element ?

Comment: If the item does not present, return empty string

Answer (score 1):

If you take the extra step to ensure your string list is trimmed, you can just use the `IndexOf()` method of `List<T>`:

```
string csv = "test1, test2, test3, test4";      
List<string> names = csv.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
```

Then your `NextInString()` method (I think this is a poorly named method) would look like this:

```
private static string NextInString(List<string> names, string userName)
{       
    int index = names.IndexOf(userName);

    if(names.Count - 1 == index || index == -1)
    {
        return "No result";
    }
    else
    {
        return names[index + 1];
    }
}
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BnTr6C)

Comment: Technically, `IndexOf` isn't part of LINQ. It is a direct member of [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx), not an extension method defined in `System.Linq`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner you are absolutely correct, I had a brain fart

Comment: Any suggestion for a better name?

Comment: Maybe `GetNextUsernameInList` or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq like this:

```
string userName = "abc";
string listOfNames = "abc,xyz,123";

var names = listOfNames
    .Split(',')
    .Select((n, i) => new {name = n, index =i} )
    .ToArray();

var firstMatch = names.FirstOrDefault(n => n.name == userName);
var result = firstMatch == null
    ? string.Empty
    : firstMatch.index == names.Length - 1
        ? string.Empty
        : names[firstMatch.index + 1].name;
```

Comment: Or, you can use `var index = names.Where(n => n.name == userName).Select(x => (int?)x.index).FirstOrDefault() ?? -1; var result = names[index + 1].name;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the LINQ approach:

```
string NextInString(string listOfNames, string userName)
{
    if(listOfNames == string.Empty || userName == string.Empty) return string.Empty;

    var names = listOfNames.Split(',');
    return names
        .SkipWhile(x => x != userName)
        .Skip(1)
        .FirstOrDefault() ?? names.Last();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a nice little extension method to do this after the string is split, like so:

```
static class IListExtensions
{
    public static T FindItemAfter<T>(this IList<T> list, T targetItem)
    {
        return list[list.IndexOf(targetItem)+ 1];
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = "cat,dog,rat".Split(',');
    Console.WriteLine(list.FindItemAfter("cat"));
    Console.WriteLine(list.FindItemAfter("dog"));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It returns:

> dog
>   rat

---

This overload will allow you to specify a default value that gets returned if the requested item isn't found, or the next item would be outside the list.

```
public static T FindItemAfter<T>(this IList<T> list, T targetItem, T defaultValue)
{
    var index = list.IndexOf(targetItem);
    if (index == -1 || index >= list.Count - 1)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    return list[index + 1];
}
```

Comment: What happens when you put "rat" as the input?  What happens if you put "bird" as the input?

Comment: For an item not in the list (bird), it returns the first item in the list. For the last item in the list (rat), it throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.  That behavior can easily be customized if desired.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this?

```
var s = listOfNames.Split(',');
for (var i = 0; i < s.count; i++)
{
    if (i == s.count - 1)
    {
        return string.Format("No user after {0} was found", userName);
    }
    else if (s[i] == userName)
    {
        return s[i + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is shorter than mine, thanks. However, please edit your answer to get rid of `IndexOutOfRange` exception

Comment: Fair enough its fixed.

Comment: What if userName doesn't match any name in s?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 No, OP returns last item in this case

Comment: You could argue a method named NextInString returning something not next in string is bad naming convention.